# Snowflake function how to input IN statment to function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I have function in Snowflake where I would like to input a variable there contains a IN statment for a query.

It works when I only have one item:

```
select * from table(my_function('62696'))
```

But I can not figure out how to do when I have more items, I have tried different ways like:

```
select * from table(my_function(''62696','62695''))
select * from table(my_function('\'62696\',\'62695\''))
```

But no of them does work.

Comment: Or alternative if it is possible to input JSON and then "unpack" JSON so it fit into a IN () statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did solve it with by call the function with:

```
select * from table(my_function('62696,62695'))
```

In the function I use it like this:

```
IN (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(MY_INPUT, ',')))
```